# How does strcmp work for 2d arrays?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, strcmp

I am trying to see how strcmp function works in C for 2d arrays. Let's say I already have read 4 strings in using a 2d array. The "4" in the array is the number of strings and the "20" in the array is the max length of the string. I am supposed to ask for user input for the objects put in the object 2d array, but I hardcoded it to make it easier for you to understand the question.

The 2d array is declared as

```
char objects[4][20] = {{Can},
                       {Laptop},
                       {Bag},
                       {Board}};


//The above code is the 2d array containing four strings

int i;
char target[5][20];

printf("Enter the object you want to search for: \n");
scanf("%s", &target);


int check = 0;
check = strcmp(target, objects);
//printf("Check: %d\n", check);//I was trying to print check itself to know 
//what the value actually is

if (check == 0)
{
    printf("Yes the object you searched is among the list");
}
else
{
    printf("No sorry, the object you searched is not among the list");
}
```

Please let me know if I am doing the check wrong or not, because the output shows that the object is not among the list whenever I search for "Can" but it prints that the object is among the list whenever I search any of the other objects in the list after Can.

Comment: This char target[5][20];

scanf("%s", &target);
does not make sense.

Comment: `strcmp(const char *, const char *)` expects a pointer to a `char`, not `strcmp(target, ..)` which is passing a pointer to an array 20 of `char`.  IOWs, `strcmp()` does not work with 2D arrays.

Comment: How does this even compile?

Comment: char target[5][20] is the declaration of the array which im searching. And "scanf("%s", &target);" is me trying to ask the user input for what the user wants to search.

Comment: You appear to be missing quotation marks in what I think you mean to be string literals in your array initializer.

Comment: @chux is there a different function for 2D character arrays? That's how far our professor taught us so far. I am just trying to see if both strings are the same or not. I don't need the length itself.

Comment: @selbie "How does this even compile?" - Very easy! It is enough to write your own compiler. That is all.:)

Comment: @FarSight, a *bona fide* 2D array is an array of arrays.  Each element is a 1D array, and can be treated as such in every way.  You do not need different functions for handling arrays that are elements of other arrays.

Comment: No standard function for 2D arrays.  Call `strcmp()` up to 4 times.  e.g. `for (i=0; i< 4; i++) { strcmp(object[i], input_buffer) ...`  @vlad has a good answer.

Comment: You can't just throw a 2d array at `strcmp` and expect it to somehow "know" its shape and adapt its behavior accordingly.  Instead, you need to pass a *slice* of the array to `strcmp`, so that it sees a 1d array.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that what you mean is the following

```
char objects[][20] = { "Can", "Laptop", "Bag", "Board" };
const size_t N = sizeof( objects ) / sizeof( *objects );

char target[20] = "Bag";

size_t i = 0;

while ( i < N &&  !( strcmp( objects[i], target ) == 0 ) ) i++;

if ( i != N)
{
    printf("Yes the object you searched is among the list");
}
else
{
    printf("No sorry, the object you searched is not among the list");
}
```

That is you are going to determine whether a given string is present in a two-dimensional character array of strings.

Comment: Are you using pointers in the second line: "const size_t N = sizeof( objects ) / sizeof( *objects );"                                                                                     We haven't been taught how to use pointers yet.  And I can't leave the first 2d array as blank for the the size. I am not sure why.

Comment: @FarSight I am using the array designator that in the expression with the unary operator * is converted to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: Interesting to use different semantics `i < N` and `i != N`.  I'd expect the same for both to add clarity.

Comment: @FarSight, there is very little you can do with arrays that does not actually use pointers, whether explicitly or implicitly.  But if doing so explictly makes you nervous then you can rewrite that line as `const size_t N = sizeof( objects ) / sizeof( objects[0] );`

Comment: @JohnBollinger sorry it's not really not about being nervous. It's just that we barely covered the topic of pointers in our class, and our professor said to stay away from them until we have a better grasp of how it works. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @FarSight You can just write const size_t N = 4; and then char objects[N][20] = { "Can", "Laptop", "Bag", "Board" }; This has a drawback that if you want to add one more initializer to the array you have to make changes in two lines.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow This line is shown as an error for me:                                                                 "char objects[][20] = { "Can", "Laptop", "Bag", "Board" };" as I am not entering any values inside the first brackets of objects                                         The error shown is: "incomplete type is not allowed".                                               Another question i have is why did you declare a const rather than just a regular integer for "N" and "i".

Comment: @FarSight It is a complete type. I think that the reason of the error is some other statement.

Comment: @FarSight As for the second question then if an array is defined its size can not be changed even if it is a variable length array.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow could you please explain the line:  "i < N &&  !( strcmp( objects[i], target ) == 0 )". I am not getting any errors now, but when I enter a target value which is not in the list, it returns that there is no match found, but when even I try a match in the list, it still returns as no match found.

Comment: @FarSight This loop looks through all elements of the array starting from the index 0 up to N and compare each element with the target string until either the target strig is found or the index will be equal to N.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow do you know why it returns as "No sorry, the object you searched is not among the list" no matter what I input for the target value. I checked to make sure I typed in the same boolean operators as your code, but I am still missing something it seems. That code works if I try it on main as it is. But when try to use that as a function, i don't know what goes wrong. It does compile and run, but it always gives same output as "no match"

Comment: @FarSight All you need is to supply your string to the code I showed. If you are entering strings using fgets then you have to remove the appended new line character '\n' from the string.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow no im not using fgets, I am using scanf like this:                    
    char target[20];
    printf("Enter the object you want to search: ");
    scanf("%s", &target);

Comment: @FarSight Use scanf( "%s", target ); where target a one-dimensional character array.